# C#, LINQ. How to find an element within group of elements

Tags: c#, linq

Imagine you have `int[] data = new int [] { 1, 2, 1, 1, 3, 2 }`

I need sub-array with only those which conform to a condition `data[i] > data[i-1] && data[i] > data[i + 1]`... i.e. I need all items which stick over their immediate neighbours.

From example above I should get `{ 2, 3 }`

Can it be done in LINQ?

Thanks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
data.Where((val, index)=>(index == 0 || val > data[index - 1]) 
                      && (index == data.Length - 1 || val > data[index + 1]));
```